# What exactly is a "Combo List", and why is this site providing them for free?

Tags: email, data-leakage

After asking for e-mail lists the other day, I got linked to this: https://combo-list.com/

This is a very strange "blog" which appears to be regularly publishing (or linking to, rather) lists of e-mail addresses which have supposedly been leaked in data breaches. I have no interest in the passwords, but it seems to also include those. I'm not sure if those are really the passwords to the e-mail accounts, or passwords for something else entirely.

My interest in this has nothing to do with using somebody else's e-mail account.

They don't mention what a "combo list" is, and I cannot figure this out from searching or thinking. It seems like the blog assumes that everyone knows what it is.

I also thought it was a fake site at first, but eventually did manage to download a list, and it appears real. But then again, who knows what kind of information really is in those lists?

I basically wonder why anyone would run such a site, and regularly update it. Why would they give out this info to the public like this? What's in it for them? Why would they want more spammers to send e-mails to these victims of data breaches?

Comment: At first glance I think it's short for "combination", as in they are giving away email/password combinations.

Comment: It says "user-pass combo list" ...

Answer (score 3):

Combo is short for combination, so combo lists are lists containing combinations of usernames/emails and passwords.

They are used for bruteforce attacks. The benefit compared to separate username and password lists is that combo lists are expected to contain a higher likelihood of success.

They may eg stem from data leaks or previous successful bruteforce attacks. The idea is that they (used to) work on some websites, and because users reuse passwords, they may work on other sites as well.

> Why would they give out this info to the public like this? What's in it for them?

Why do people share anything with others? Fame, recognition, helpfulness, money (via ads), boredom?

> Why would they want more spammers to send e-mails to these victims of data breaches?

It's not so much about spamming (lists of email addresses would be enough for that), but about gaining access to other users accounts. Eg to gain free stuff (say a netflix account) or for more nefarious purposes (stealing money, credit cards, etc).